# Get typeOf[Int] from typeOf[List[Int]]

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

what I want to do is: Get `typeOf[Int]` from `tpe`. It should generalize to any type other than `Int`.

```
val tpe = typeOf[List[Int]]
val ??? = typeOf[Int]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val tpe = typeOf[List[Int]]
tpe.typeArgs.head == typeOf[Int] // true
```

or

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
type T = List[Int]
val tpe = typeOf[T]
tpe.dealias.typeArgs.head == typeOf[Int] // true
```